# How browser handles `no-cache=“Set-Cookie”` in Cache-Control header

Tags: http, cache-control, setcookie, no-cache

I'm wondering how browser would handle the situation when `no-cache: "Set-Cookie"` is presented in Cache-Control.

I did some research online and the result was different. Some say it won't cache set-cookie header, others say it won't cache the content if set-cookie header is presented.
Here is one of the reference:
https://www.w3.org/Protocols/HTTP/Issues/cache-private.html

> The "no-cache" directive on a response message indicates that parts 
>      of the message must never be cached. If no list of field names is 
>      given, then the entire message must not be cached; otherwise, only 
>      the information within the header fields identified by the list of 
>      names must not be cached and the remainder of the message is 
>      believed to be cachable.

For example:

```
cache-control: public, max-age=2592000, no-cache="Set-Cookie"
```

Based on the research, `public, max-age=2592000` tells browser to cache 30 days and not cache Set-Cookie header. However, I'm seeing all MISS in intermediate CDN.

Comment: Does your browser follow "cache 30 days and not cache Set-Cookie header" behaviour?

Comment: Thank you. It turned out that I had mismatched the no-cache in cache-control

Comment: @JLeGend, Have same issue, what was mismatched in your case? Thanks